# multiprocessing.dummy pool: Можно ли передать в функцию map несколько аргументов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, multiprocessing

читаю про параллельное выполнение. 
возник вопрос

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def f(x,y,argv):
     #do something

pool = ThreadPool(4)
pool.map(f, params) #можно сделать так? - [x,y,[argv]]
```

Можно ли передать в функцию map несколько аргументов? (x,y,*argv)

Вообще, читал про потоки, потоки ведь все равно не выполняются параллельно из-за GIL? А процессы полностью автономны и параллельны?

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Python multiprocessing pool.map for multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5442910/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def f(x, y, argv, k=1):
     print(vars())

def decor(func):
    def wrap(arg):
        a, kw = arg
        return func(*a, **kw)
    return wrap

params = (
    ([0, 1, [2, 3]], dict(k=4)),
    ([5, 6, [7]], {}),
)
pool = ThreadPool(4)
pool.map(decor(f), params) #можно сделать так? - [x,y,[argv]]

# out:
# {'argv': [2, 3], 'y': 1, 'k': 4, 'x': 0}
# {'argv': [7], 'y': 6, 'k': 1, 'x': 5}
```

Comment: Можно starmap использовать, чтобы не создавать обёртки для `f`